# How to play audio on button click (recycler view)

Tags: android

How do I play an audio from `raw` folder on button click? Here, I'm using `recyclerview` to show the list of audios. But when click play, it doesn't play any sound.

```
private Button btnPlay;

btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try{
            mp.setDataSource(ss.getSoundURI());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
    public void playSound(final String fileName) {
    MediaPlayer mpPlayer = null;
    try {
        int fileId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", getPackageName());
        mpPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, fileId);
        mpPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mpPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mpPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (mpPlayer != null)
            mpPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** use file name without file extension. for example if your file name is *file1.wav* you should send file1 as a file name to function NOT *file1.wav* .

**NOTE:** In first line I defined the mpPlayer and initialize it because i want to use it in the catch block.